# Iterating through a list of items using for-loop

Tags: java, android, list, for-loop

I have tried iterating through the list but am only getting the last entry item of the list.I want to iterate through the list adding each 'profit' item from the list to `current_profit` and finally be able to return the accrued `current_profit`. The method `getFinanceList()` returns a list of size 2 as shown.

This is my debug log. It shows a list of size 2 that is returned from my method in the code give. using `getFinanceList()`.

```
 ((FinanceRepository)this).financeList = {ArrayList@6012}  size = 2
 this = {FinanceRepository@6004} 
 current_expenditure = 0
 current_income = 0
 current_profit = -1000
 farmerApp = {BoxStore@6010} 
 financeBox = {Box@6011} 
 financeList = {ArrayList@6012}  size = 2
0 = {Finance@6025} 
 __boxStore = {BoxStore@6010} 
 category = "farm"
 finance_type = "Income"
 id = 1
 name = "jembe"
 notes = "hdgsbsbsb.."
 payment_type = "Cash"
 profit = {Integer@6032} 500  //this profit
 quantity = "5"
 total_amount = "500"
 total_expenditure = {Integer@6035} 0
 total_income = {Integer@6036} 500
 transaction_date = "17-7-2019"
 user = {ToOne@6038} 
 mCallbacks = null
 shadow$_klass_ = {Class@4418} "class 
com.example.e_farmer.models.Finance"
 shadow$_monitor_ = -2069821990
1 = {Finance@6026} 
 __boxStore = {BoxStore@6010} 
 category = "farm"
 finance_type = "Expenditure"
 id = 2
 name = "spade"
 notes = "bdhxhdd"
 payment_type = "Cash"
 profit = {Integer@6045} -1000 //And this profit
 quantity = "5"
 total_amount = "1000"
 total_expenditure = {Integer@6048} 1000
 total_income = {Integer@6049} 0
 transaction_date = "18-7-2019"
 user = {ToOne@6051} 
 mCallbacks = null
 shadow$_klass_ = {Class@4418} "class 
com.example.e_farmer.models.Finance"
 shadow$_monitor_ = -1997268469
 shadow$_klass_ = {Class@5986} "class 
com.example.e_farmer.repositories.FinanceRepository"
 shadow$_monitor_ = -2070028009
 current_profit = -1000
```

This is how my code is. Note that the class Finance is my model class

```
   public MutableLiveData<Integer> getProfit() {

   //the method getFinanceList returns a financeList of size 2 as  illustrated above in the debug code.

    getFinanceList();

    int current_profit = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < financeList.size(); i++) {
        Finance finance = financeList.get(i);
        current_profit =+finance.getProfit();
    }

    Log.d(TAG, "getProfit: " + current_profit);

    MutableLiveData<Integer> profit_data = new MutableLiveData<>();
    profit_data.setValue(current_profit);

    return profit_data;
}
```

Am expecting the current_profit to get profit of the first item and the second item and have a total i.e 500 + (-1000) = - 500 but am only getting the last item (-1000) only.

Comment: current_profit += finance.getProfit(); try this

Comment: Thank you very much @Lakhwinder Singh.I think i should rest now.enough of coding for today.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wrote `current_profit =+finance.getProfit()` where you meant `current_profit += finance.getProfit()`. You just assign the value, with unary `+` called on it, which does nothing. The operator of adding a value to the previous value is `+=`.

Answer (score 1):

The corrected method, the problem was =+, changed into +=

```
public MutableLiveData<Integer> getProfit() {

   //the method getFinanceList returns a financeList of size 2 as  illustrated above in the debug code.

    getFinanceList();

    int current_profit = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < financeList.size(); i++) {
        Finance finance = financeList.get(i);
        current_profit +=finance.getProfit();
    }

    Log.d(TAG, "getProfit: " + current_profit);

    MutableLiveData<Integer> profit_data = new MutableLiveData<>();
    profit_data.setValue(current_profit);

    return profit_data;
}
```